# UWP Textblock Expand

Tags: uwp, expand, textblock

Using UWP, I have a grid which show rows of data, one column of data can contain some large amounts of text in a TextBlock. I want to limit the row definition height to 80 (MaxHeight) so it all looks even(ish), but if there is a large amount of text in one of the TextBlocks, I want to show an 'expand' button which removes the row height restriction, so all the text can be seen in the TextBlock.

Is this possible? What's the best approach, I've looked at VisualStateManagers, Triggers (where are they in UWP!?) and user controls - any thoughts?

The following XAML is used to display the data in a grid using a DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListItem">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Opacity="{Binding Master, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToOpacity}}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="28" />
            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="100" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="200" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="&#xEADF;" FontSize="16" Padding="2" Style="{StaticResource IconTextBlock}" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Code}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewTextBlock}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Ref1}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewTextBlock}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Description}" Style="{StaticResource ListViewTextBlock}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxHeight="84" x:Name="tbDescription" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding State}"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewTextBlock}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding SubType}"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewTextBlock}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" Text="{Binding Category}"  Style="{StaticResource ListViewTextBlock}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

It's the description TextBlock which I want to make 'expandable' by the user.

Comment: Set MaxLength of TextBlock to your desired characters, and then set `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"`.

Comment: I don't have a max length of my TextBlock it's usually 1 to 4 lines, but sometimes can be several - I want to show 1 to 4 lines by default, but give the user the option to show more if they want

Comment: Could you share the XAML code you are using now?

Comment: Added DataTemplate XAML, as you can see, fixed row height, but want the user to be able to expand the TextBlock to see all the data (if there is any to display!)